# Parsing JSON payload and displaying it error in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to display data from a JSON payload.

```
Future<void> getItems() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoaded = true;
    });
    var client = http.Client();
    String parameters;

    parameters = '?address=711%20Culberson%20Ave%2C%20San%20Antonio%2C%20TX%2C%2078225';
                

    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(
          "https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties?address=711%20Culberson%20Ave%2C%20San%20Antonio%2C%20TX%2C%2078225");
          //"https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties?address=5500%20Grand%20Lake%20Dr%2C%20San%20Antonio%2C%20TX%2C%2078244");
      final response = await client.get(
        url,
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key':
              '51ced1b32emsh509f82e1d58ae16p1ad6e6jsn75d75166a8b4',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com'
        },
      );
      log("response body ${response.body}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // decode the json
        for (var i in jsonData) {
          log("i $i");
          propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));
          // propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));
        }
      } else {
        print('Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = false;
      });
      log("error $e");
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoaded = false;
    });
```

This is the JSON from the log in the terminal window:

```
[log] response body [{"addressLine1":"711 Culberson Ave","city":"San Antonio","state":"TX","zipCode":"78225","formattedAddress":"711 Culberson Ave, San Antonio, TX 78225","bedrooms":2,"squareFootage":1340,"yearBuilt":1945,"county":"Bexar","assessorID":"09296-000-0120","legalDescription":"NCB 9296 BLK LOT 12","subdivision":"CONV A/S CODE","ownerOccupied":true,"bathrooms":1,"lotSize":7318,"propertyType":"Single Family","lastSaleDate":"1999-12-09T00:00:00.000Z","features":{"architectureType":"Contemporary","cooling":true,"coolingType":"Central","exteriorType":"Asbestos Shingle","floorCount":1,"foundationType":"Pier / Post & Beam","garage":true,"garageType":"Mixed","heating":true,"heatingType":"Forced Air","roofType":"Asphalt","roomCount":6,"unitCount":1},"taxAssessment":{"2022":{"value":179230,"land":32940,"improvements":146290}},"propertyTaxes":{"2022":{"total":843}},"owner":{"names":["SANTOS T ESCOBAR","SANTOS MARIA D ESCOBAR"],"mailingAddress":{"id":"711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225","addressLine1":"711 Culberson Ave","city":"San Antonio","state":"TX","zipCode":"78225"}},"id":"711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225","longitude":-98.539988,"latitude":29.382409}]
```

This is the parsed data again from the log in the terminal window:

```
[log] i {addressLine1: 711 Culberson Ave, city: San Antonio, state: TX, zipCode: 78225, formattedAddress: 711 Culberson Ave, San Antonio, TX 78225, bedrooms: 2, squareFootage: 1340, yearBuilt: 1945, county: Bexar, assessorID: 09296-000-0120, legalDescription: NCB 9296 BLK LOT 12, subdivision: CONV A/S CODE, ownerOccupied: true, bathrooms: 1, lotSize: 7318, propertyType: Single Family, lastSaleDate: 1999-12-09T00:00:00.000Z, features: {architectureType: Contemporary, cooling: true, coolingType: Central, exteriorType: Asbestos Shingle, floorCount: 1, foundationType: Pier / Post & Beam, garage: true, garageType: Mixed, heating: true, heatingType: Forced Air, roofType: Asphalt, roomCount: 6, unitCount: 1}, taxAssessment: {2022: {value: 179230, land: 32940, improvements: 146290}}, propertyTaxes: {2022: {total: 843}}, owner: {names: [SANTOS T ESCOBAR, SANTOS MARIA D ESCOBAR], mailingAddress: {id: 711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225, addressLine1: 711 Culberson Ave, city: San Antonio, state: TX, zipCode: 78225}}, id: 711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225, longitude: -98.539988, latitude: 29.382409}
```

When debugging, the var i = the JSON data. I was thinking it should equal the number of elements in the JSON. The code loops through once to PropertyList.add() and then errors with the error message of **error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'**

```
for (var i in jsonData) {
          log("i $i");
          propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));
          // propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));
        }
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how does your .fromJson(i) function looks like? is it nullable ?